# Regex match this, or that, or this AND that within a url

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm using the following regular expression to match a url within an element:

```
(<.*?>)((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?)([\w-]+)((?:\.\w+)(?:\.\w+)*)(.*?)(<\/.*?>)
```

This works fine so far, except it will also match these kinds of elements:

```
<b>I.Am.Not.A.Url</b>
```

This is because my expression is looking for `http://`or `https://`followed by `www.`, except they are all optional. So it would match even if none of those are present.

What I want to be able to do, is match if either or all of them are present within the string:

```
<b>http://website.com/</b> - Match
<b>http://www.website.com/</b> - Match
<b>https://website.com/</b> - Match
<b>https://www.website.com/</b> - Match
<b>www.website.com</b> - Match
<b>website.com</b> - No match
```

Comment: Perhaps, just replace `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?` with `(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)` to make at least 1 of them obligatory.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Huh.. didn't realise it was that simple. My bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?` matches an optional `https://` or `http://` and then an optional  `www.`, you will get matches where these patterns are missing.

To require one of them, convert this pattern part to an alternation:

```
(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|www\.)
```

This will make it match

- `https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?` - a protocol with an optional `www.` after it
- `|` - or
- `www\.` - a `www.` substring.

Se a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/NSLIRS/2).

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way that I can put them in the same group? If they both are present, they are put into 2 groups because of the following `([\w-]+)` in my expression.

Comment: Could you please provide a regex fiddle? What do you mean by "they are put into 2 groups"?

Comment: Ok, got it. `(<[^>]*>)(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?|www\.)([\w-]+)((?:\.\w+)(?:\.\w+)*)([\s\S]*?)(<\/[^>]*>)`. I updated the answer and added a fiddle link. Note I replaced `.` with `[\s\S]` to match any char, and the `.*?` inside tags is replaced with `[^>]`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :D